# Bubble sort object by any property?

Tags: excel, bubble-sort, vba

I am using a bubble sort function to sort objects by their properties. Unfortunately I have had to write one function for every property. Is there any way to generalize the functions below.

Instead of writing

```
SortArticlesByVolume(a)
SortArticlesByLenght(a)
```

I would like to write something like:

```
SortArticles(a, volume)
```

Sub SortArticlesByVolume(ByRef articles As Variant)

```
Dim sorted As Boolean
Dim i As Integer

sorted = False
Do While Not sorted
    sorted = True
    For i = 0 To UBound(articles) - 1
        If articles(i).volume < articles(i + 1).volume Then
            Set temp = articles(i + 1)
            Set articles(i + 1) = articles(i)
            Set articles(i) = temp
            sorted = False
        End If
    Next i
Loop
```

End Sub

Sub SortArticlesBylenght(ByRef articles As Variant)

```
Dim sorted As Boolean
Dim i As Integer

sorted = False
Do While Not sorted
    sorted = True
    For i = 0 To UBound(articles) - 1
        If articles(i).lenght < articles(i + 1).lenght Then
            Set temp = articles(i + 1)
            Set articles(i + 1) = articles(i)
            Set articles(i) = temp
            sorted = False
        End If
    Next i
Loop
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

I don't think VBA allows you to use reflection, so I suppose you would need to rewrite your article class and add methods to get properties by name, such as `article.get("volume")` to get the volume. If you don't have too many fields it would probably be the easiest way.
The get function would still require some sort of Select or If/Then statements but it would be encapsulated in the class itself.